# Как ускорить MYSQL UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

Есть штук 1000 запросов на обновление. Пробовал делать через START TRANSACTION, но всё равно медленно

```
START TRANSACTION; 
UPDATE maintbl set is_ar1=1 and is_deal=1 where rkk_app_sequence LIKE '%2007993381%'; 
UPDATE maintbl set is_ar1=1 and is_deal=1 where rkk_app_sequence LIKE '%2007833405%'; 
UPDATE maintbl set is_ar1=1 and is_deal=1 where rkk_app_sequence LIKE '%2007485592%'; 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Использование такого LIKE вынуждает базу проходиться по всем строкам в поисках соответствий, такое вы никак не ускорите. Нельзя ли переписать запрос или перепроектировать базу так, чтобы этого LIKE не было?

Comment: А если SET во всех запросах одинаковый, то, очевидно, их можно объединить в один запрос с несколькими LIKE

Comment: Не изменяя подхода, тут нечего оптимизировать. Внимательно смотрите на поле `rkk_app_sequence` и паттерн для него. Имеет ли поле некий предопределённый формат? не располагается ли искомая группа в нём в определённом месте (постоянное смещение, разделитель и пр.) - если да, создайте generated column, индексируйте, и используйте прямой отбор по этой колонке.

Answer (score 0):

А если так попробовать?

```
UPDATE maintbl set is_ar1=1, is_deal=1 where 
    rkk_app_sequence LIKE '%2007993381%' OR 
    rkk_app_sequence LIKE '%2007833405%' OR 
    rkk_app_sequence LIKE '%2007485592%'
```

Comment: а это насколько быстро?